# test-path returns permission denied - how to do error handling

Tags: powershell, exception

i try to do error handling within my powershell script. but i always get an fatal. i tried a few things, e. g. try{ } catch{ } - but i did it not get to work.

any ideas or Solutions?

```
Function Check-Path($Db)
{
    If ((Test-Path $Db) –eq $false) {
        Write-Output "The file $Db does not   exist"
        break
    }
}
```

It Returns:

```
Test-Path : Zugriff verweigert
In K:\access\access.ps1:15 Zeichen:6
+ If ((Test-Path $Db) -eq $false) {
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (K:\ss.mdb:String) [Test-Path],     UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somewhat confusingly `Test-Path` actually generates an error in a number of cases. Set the standard ErrorAction parameter to SilentlyContinue to ignore it.

```
if ((Test-Path $Db -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $false) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer directly. So this has to do:

I strongly disagree with your answer. Test-Path does show $false when you run it against a network share that is not accessible, but it will be false also (without Exception) when the Server is not reachable.

So your answer simply ignores anything but a reachable share.

What is neccessary however is a try-catch-block that handles this better:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [boolean]$returnException = $true,
    [boolean]$returnFalse = $false
)

## Try-Catch Block:

try {
    if ($returnException) {
        ## Server Exists, but Permission is denied.
        Test-Path -Path "\\Exists\Data\" -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
    } elseif ($returnFalse) {
        ## Server does not exist
        Test-Path -Path "\\NoExists\Data\" -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
    }
} catch [UnauthorizedAccessException] {
    ## Unauthorized
    write-host "No Access Exception"

} catch {
    ## an error has occurred
    write-host "Any other Exception here"
}
```

The really important part however is the ErrorAction on the Test-Path command, otherwise the exception will be wrapped around a system management error and is thus not catchable. This is in detail explained here:

[PowerShell catching typed exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381237/powershell-catching-typed-exceptions/8381798#8381798)