# Catch last inner exception when using the -ErrorAction Stop flag

Tags: powershell, exception

Here is the code:

```
Try{
    $connection = Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop -ComputerName "test"
    return $connection.StatusCode.ToString()
}
Catch [System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException]{
    return "Ping Exception"
}
Catch [Exception]{
    return "Unexpected exception"
}
```

Now, let's consider the case where the `-ComputerName` would not be found, this would return me a `System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException`. But, in the above code the output would be  `Unexpected exception`.

Refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8381798/7692463) answer, I should use `System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException` to catch it.

Now my question is, how can I catch the last inner exception when using the `-ErrorAction Stop` flag. Should I just throw a `PingException` ? It doesn't seems to be a good idea since I can't be sure a `PinException` really is the cause of the `ErrorAction` trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that when using `-ErrorAction Stop` flag, non-terminating errors are wrapped and thrown as type `System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException`. Therefore a solution would be to walk through the *exception tree* like so,

```
Try{
    $connection = Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop -ComputerName "test"
    return $connection.StatusCode.ToString()
}
Catch [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]{
    $exception = $_.Exception
    #Walk through Exception tree
    while ($exception.InnerException) {
      $exception  = $exception.InnerException
    }
    #Return only the last inner exception
    return $exception.Message
}
Catch [Exception]{
    return "Unexpected exception"
}
```

**EDIT**

Note that my code is returning the last inner exception **Message** as a string. The same logic can be used to find other information if needed.

Comment: `Test-Connection` doesn't throw an `ActionPreferenceStopException`.

Comment: It does when using `-ErrorAction Stop` flag. Run it yourself.

Comment: That is extremely bizarre.. Just as a tip, you don't need to catch [exception], that's the default.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 it's not bizzare, this actually is what -ErrorAction does in case of  non-terminating errors. They are wrapped and thrown as type `System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 And I wanted to be explicit for the sake of the answer. Good insight though thanks !