# Powershell script - gci

Tags: windows, powershell, exception, get-childitem, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm trying to divide output into two files with following script:

```
try {
    gci C:\Windows\System32 -r -Force | % {
        if (!$_.PsIsContainer) {
            $_.FullName;
            $file = $_.FullName
        }
    } > paths.txt
} catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException] {
    $file > errors.txt
}
```

I'm aware that you can't catch non-terminating scripts with `catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]`, but I don't want to use `-ErrorAction Stop` with `catch [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]` either (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381237/powershell-catching-typed-exceptions/8381798#8381798)), because I won't get all file paths.

Comment: As a side issue, try to avoid using aliases (`gci`, `%`) in scripts as it can make them harder to maintain.  Also, if you are using PowerShell v3 or later you don't need to use `$_.PsisContainer`, but can use the `-Directory`/`-File` switches for `Get-Childitem`: [FileSystem Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/filesystem-provider?view=powershell-6)

Comment: @boxdog Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
$epath2 = $null

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\System32 -Recurse -Force -Directory -ErrorVariable epath2 |
foreach {
     if ($?) {
       Out-File -InputObject $_.FullName -FilePath c:\test\paths.txt -Append
    } 
}

if ($epath2) {
  $epath2 | 
  foreach {
     ($_.Exception -split "'")[1] | Out-File -FilePath c:\test\errors.txt -Append
  }
}
```

catch the errors in the -ErrorAction variable and send to errors.txt as a second pass.  There may be other errors than access denied but you'll know which folders were showing problems